# method, return in a while

Tags: php, while-loop, return

I'm working in a class and I have a method which returns :

```
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){
        $temp[$i] = new Membres($donnees['id_membres']);
        return '' . $temp[$i]->getPseudo() . '<br>';
        $i++;
```

it only returns the first data of the while, and when I'm using echo instead of return it's working but the printing is in top of the page.

Comment: return **exits the current function** and this also implies it **exits the while loop** - a function can only exit *once* - no resuming! Instead, create/load an appropriate data structure and return that at the end of the function *after* the while loop ends.

Comment: you need all the Membres? or just the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$var = '';
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){
        $temp[$i] = new Membres($donnees['id_membres']);
        $var .= '' . $temp[$i]->getPseudo() . '<br>';
        $i++;
}
return $var;
```